# React-bootstrap centering checkboxes in columns

Tags: reactjs, css, react-bootstrap

I have a `ListGroup` with `ListGroupItems` that get populated by some data. Part of that data is a description, which obviously varies in length.

```
<ListGroup className="signal-info-container">
  {
    signalConstants[this.props.signalType].map((signal, i) => (
      <ListGroupItem key={i}>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={3}>
            {signal.name}
          </Col>
          <Col xs={5}>
            {signal.description}
          </Col>
          <Col xs={3} className="aggregation">
            <Checkbox inline={true}></Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline={true}></Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline={true}></Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline={true}></Checkbox>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </ListGroupItem>
    ))
  }
</ListGroup>
```

Sometimes that description needs to wrap (as seen below).

[image: Wrapped descriptions]

What I would like to have happen is for the checkboxes in the right column vertically align in the center of the col.

I have tried to override `react-bootstrap` with some custom css. The following css results in the previous image.

```
.aggregation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Not sure how relevant it is, but the columns have a height of 0px. What confuses me is why the single-line descriptions are centered, but multi-line descriptions are not. Here is an image of the 0px cols:

[image: 0px height col]

I have noticed that there seems to be some sort of label applied to the checkbox which is getting centered by the applied CSS, but I need it applied on the actual checkbox instead. I have just removed the `title` attribute from my checkboxes. The effect is still the same (labels weren't showing up anyways).

Comment: It looks like a CSS issue. Provide a working example (snippet/fiddler) that we can play with in order to provide a solution.

Comment: Okay, give me a second. I'll get a basic example.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that I'm going to be able to create an example, I don't have the time to recreate all the layers of my app. I'll try to keep working on this and answer my own question for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply `display: flex; align-items: center;` to the entire `<tr>` so it recognizes the multi-line descriptions. So you should add a class to the `<Row>` that uses these rules.

Comment: This centered the columns in the row, which is progress! But it did not center the checkboxes quite right. Here is what it looks like right now. It seems there is some label that is preventing me from centering the checkbox. https://imgur.com/N9jwWti

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's strange. Try adding a `margin: 0` to the checkboxes. But you're right, it looks like some element is pushing them out of place.

Comment: `margin: 0` had no effect unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your component as so:

```
<ListGroup className="signal-info-container">
  {
    signalConstants[this.props.signalType].map((signal, i) => (
      <ListGroupItem key={i}>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={3}>
            {signal.name}
          </Col>
          <Col xs={5}>
            {signal.description}
          </Col>
          <Col xs={3}>
            <CheckboxRow>
              <Checkbox title='min' inline={true}></Checkbox>
              <Checkbox title='max' inline={true}></Checkbox>
              <Checkbox title='avg' inline={true}></Checkbox>
              <Checkbox title='sum' inline={true}></Checkbox>
            </CheckboxRow>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </ListGroupItem>
    ))
  }
</ListGroup>
```

Where CheckboxRow is

```
const CheckboxRow = ({children}) => (
  <div style={
    "display": "flex",
    "justify-content": "center",
    "align-items": "center"
  }>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

or extract that CSS out to a stylesheet if you have one.

Reason for adding the extra `div` layer is that it's safer than trying to override styles on the column components, since it's purpose is not to lay elements our horizontally.

The 'justify-content: center' centers the items horizontally, 'align-items: center' centers the items vertically.

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to do the trick. This is what happens when I try this solution: https://imgur.com/jUCPcvn
I believe the issue is stemming from the label.

Comment: I mistakenly had "height: 100%" on there, I think that was wrong, it seems to inherit the height from the child.. Where are you pulling "Checkbox" from? It's hard to tell from the image, but it looks like maybe position is hard set (that little brown line above them). Can you include a screen shot with the inspector open and view the CSS applied to the checkbox?

Comment: Checkbox is an element that I imported from react-bootstrap. (`import  { 
Checkbox } from 'react-bootstrap'`). Because of bootstrap the amount of computed styles is huge, here is an image of the element and a pastebin with the corresponding styles: https://imgur.com/HFLKHYT https://pastebin.com/pWR38p8P